# What parameters should i pass to classifier.predict in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Decision Tree Classification

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Class_Dataset_final.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:9].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 9].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
# Encoding the Dependent Variable
labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)


# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Fitting Decision Tree Classification to the Training set
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green', 'blue')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Decision Tree Classification (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Visualising the Test set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_test, y_test
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Decision Tree Classification (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I have the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input.
  Model `n_features` is 9 and input `n_features` is 2 in `classfier.predict`.
```

I have basic knowledge in `python`, but this is very specific and I do not have any idea how to solve these problem, but I think it should be a quick fix.

Comment: I think the problem is because you preprocess only the train dataset, you need to preprocess the whole dataset, then split it into trainset and test set

Comment: @IWHKYB As far as I understand the code, the preprocessing (in this case: scaling) is done correctly in the question; both `X_train` and `X_test` are transformed.

Comment: As I read in different forums, transform is executed correctly as @Ralf said.

Comment: Check the shapes. You omitted much of the info, but i would guess this happens in contour prep at the ravel() call. Print out shapes there. Too lazy to check. But i hope you did not copy paste visualization code assuming 2d features now combined with your higher dimension data

Comment: In fact, this code is to one of my university lecturers and he asked me for help.
The problem is that I do not have so deep knowledge in python.
According to the compiler, the error is here :

plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))

Comment: Because you are using 2 features in that line. But above where you trained the classifier (in `classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)`) the `X_train` had 9 features. You cannot use different number of features during training and testing. As I understand, you want to plot the data onto a 2-d image, but how would you show a 9-feature vector on a 2-d grid?

Comment: @VivekKumar Do you know How should look the fixed code?
How could  I modify it in order to work?

Comment: Either change the number of features from 9 to 2 when fitting, or find different methods of visualizing.